# How to make a LaTex Library

Tags: document-configuration, tikzlibrary

Its posible to make a library to Latex? I got the principal idea of the library, but really dont know where to start, is there any tutorial (for dummies maybe, im kinda newbie in this) that explain how to begin.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As your question stands, it isn't entirely clear what you're trying to achieve: Are you looking to gather some bibliographic entries, or a set of books and tutorials about LaTeX? Please advise.

Comment: you might consider just installing [tex live](http://tug.org/texlive/), which already contains just about everything one could want.  while it's not called a "library", it is for all practical purposes the equivalent of one.

Comment: I think he wants to create a package?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I think you mean 'library' in the sense of an extension to TeX. If this is the case, check out the document [`clsguide`](http://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide) (aka. 'LaTeX2 for class and package writers'). This should tell you everything you need to know about writing packages and classes.

If you're using TeXLive, you can access clsguide by typing:

```
texdoc clsguide
```

in your shell. Fair warning: Some of the concepts in library/class creation may be a bit beyond what you've worked with thus far if you're just starting to learn [La]TeX. Might be worth polishing your skills a bit before you attempt to go onto package design.

After you get the basics of class/package creation down, you might look at the slightly meta sounding "[How to Package Your LaTeX Package](http://ctan.org/pkg/dtxtut)" (`texdoc dtxtut`) or just read the source code / documentation for [`doc.tex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/doc) for information on wraping up your package in a nice format alongside its documentation.